# How to add to a lazy list

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

Getting started with lazy loading. I have an order with order details.

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    private Lazy<List<OrderDetail>> _OrderDetails => new Lazy<List<OrderDetail>>(() => OrderService.GetOrderDetails(this.OrderId));
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails => _OrderDetails.Value;
}
```

This seems to work nicely retrieving an order but I come unstuck creating an order. Before a new order is persisted I want to add order details but, (skipping the creation of an order detail for brevity) when it comes to

```
Order.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
```

no order detail is added to the order (no exception is thrown). I assume this is because of laziness. How do I add a member to the OrderDetails list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `=>` in _OrderDetails. This is what happens:

If you call `Order.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail)`, this will access the `OrderDetails` property which in turn accesses the `_OrderDetails` property which will do a `new Lazy<List<OrderDetail>>`. This will finally create the list and you add a new element to the list.

Fine so far.

But if you then check `Order.OrderDetails` again, this will once more access the `OrderDetails` property which in turn accesses the `_OrderDetails` property which will do another `new Lazy<List<OrderDetail>>`. So you get a fresh list (without the element you just added).

The solution is simple: replace

```
private Lazy<List<OrderDetail>> _OrderDetails => 
    new Lazy<List<OrderDetail>>(() => 
        OrderService.GetOrderDetails(this.OrderId));
```

by

```
private Lazy<List<OrderDetail>> _OrderDetails;
```

and initialize it in the constructor

```
public Order()
{
    _OrderDetails = new Lazy<List<OrderDetail>>(() => 
        OrderService.GetOrderDetails(this.OrderId));
}
```

This will create the list only once on first access.

Does `OrderId` really have to be writable? If yes, you have to re-create `_OrderDetails` whenever `OrderId` changes:

```
private Guid _orderId = Guid.NewGuid();
public Guid OrderId 
{
    get { return _orderId; }
    set 
    {
        _orderId = value;
        // re-create _OrderDetails with the new value of OrderId
        _OrderDetails = new Lazy<List<OrderDetail>>(() => 
            OrderService.GetOrderDetails(this.OrderId));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Order.OrderId` is writable so an order can be initialised in a valid state. `Order.OrderId` may later be overwritten if an order is retrieved from the database. Always willing to take advice.

Comment: Maybe it is sufficient to initialize it only in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Klaus Gütter. I am trying to add lazy loading to a large existing project and I can't change the ctor of the parent class without significant refactoring.

Comment: OK, then you could implement the OrderId setter explicitely (with a backing field) and re-create _OrderDetails there

Comment: Could you make that explicit in your answer please @Klaus Gütter so I can makr it as accepted